# Auto-scan for config files from ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am creating ExtJS 6.2 application from scratch. I am pretty new to this framework so I could use some help with scaffolding of application.

The designed application is supposed to have separate 'plugins' that (on the code/packages level) will be totally separated. We also are having some kind of Router that will register some info per view name (path/controller/model/additional info). I would like it to be working in a way similar to the template method design pattern. When I add new plugin/module I also add file with specific name pattern - eg. ModuleACMEGlobalConf. I want ExtJS application (or component/class - whatever) to somehow scan whole class tree for files with such name pattern, read their contents and then put in my router config/global namespace variable.

And the question is - what is the best way to achieve that?

UPDATE:

Structure I want to have:

```
MyAppFolder  
---Module1  
.....MyConfigGlobal1.js  
---Module2  
.....MyConfigGlobal2.js  
---  
---Router.js  -> I want this file to scan whole 'MyAppFolder' tree, find files with *ConfigGlobal*.js pattern, read them and store in global namespace
```

MyConfigGlobal1.js

```
var config = { configProp1:  'test', configProp2:  'test2'}
```

MyConfigGlobal2.js

```
var config = {configProp3: 'test3', configProp4: 'test4'}
```

Router.js

```
var configsMap = EXT.SOMETHING.FIND.ME.CLASSES.FROM.TREE.WITH.NAME('*MyConfigGlobal*')
```

And I want the router to load everything (it can be on the class level, not file level) - whether it is one class or one hundred. And with this solution I do not have to change Router.js ever - just add another config class with in a new module I am creating. So there is no need to retest previous modules.

But if I am having something like this in Router:

```
var requiredConfigs = ['MyGlobalConfig1.js','MyGlobalConfig2.js']
```

And I am about to add third file/class to this list in Router it means that the policy is broken and I have to retest module1 and module2 because code common for them in some way was modified.

Comment: The Ext loader will, by default, load files it doesn't have from your app based on class definition. For example, if you ask for `Ext.create('MyApp.view.custom.Foo');`, it will try and load a file from `/appRoot/view/custom/Foo.js`. To clarify, do you want this to happen at "compile time", or at runtime?

Comment: I know that. I just want to know if I can do something like this (Ext method is a fake, it's just pseudocode):  var objList = Ext.find('MyApp.*GlobalConf')

Comment: The wildcard selector only works at a directory level, so you can do `MyApp.model.*`, but you can't do `MyApp.model.Foo*`. If you could provide a more concrete example that would help, what you're asking is certainly achievable.

Comment: The best way to do it would be to have it pulled in as part of your build. Is there any reason you can't have the module require it?

Comment: The 'Router' is a common part for all modules. And if I define that it requires another file (from new module - therefore I am adding only one line of code), all other modules must be retested again (by testers - this is company policy - not to be changed). And I want to avoid this - that's why I am asking about runtime resolve of files.

Comment: I'm not following. At some point, you need to include the module. How is that supposed to happen?

Comment: Router class will be loaded at startup of the application. I want Router to SCAN whole class-tree in search for all classes that has name that comply with my pattern. I do not want to list every config class in my Router class - I want it to be automatically resolved on Router class creation. It's like in backend Java app - classloader goes through all classes/depnendcies - if it is a *.properties files it parses it and puts in whole-app-properties-placeholder.

Comment: JS can't "query" the server in that way, you would need a pre-built list. If the purpose is to work around this "policy", why not just add a requirement for `MyApp.*` in your router? Whether you dynamically load the file or not, it seems as though you're contravening the spirit of the policy anyway.

Comment: As I said, why not just require `MyApp.*`, then you never need to change the router.

Comment: What you want to have is a server-side script that can scan the file system for installed modules, or a single file that is modified by every module setup to always contain the full list of available modules.

Answer (score 1):

Without brute forcing or a call to backend, you can't. It is a browser limitation.

The reason is security. Because if you could, then one could theoretically use JavaScript to scan websites and get directory structures, probably seeing or even accessing files without authorization.

The best and perhaps most efficient way is to write a method that scans your web directory in your backend and deliver a list like you mentioned in your `requiredConfigs` idea as JSON object. Even something like

```
<script type="text/javascript" source="configFiles.js"></script>
```

in your index.html file will work reliably. Then you have a list of files to be loaded. Then you can modify your bootstrap file in a way that these files will be included in your required list, which can be done with pure JavaScript, right before ExtJS is initialized.